# Ошибка при установке в Pycharm

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, vimeo

```
pip install django-vimeo
Collecting django-vimeo
  Using cached django-vimeo-0.1.8.tar.gz (13 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Collecting PyVimeo<0.4,>=0.3.2
  Using cached PyVimeo-0.3.10.tar.gz (5.8 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Collecting Django<1.10,>=1.5
  Using cached Django-1.9.13-py2.py3-none-any.whl (6.6 MB)
Collecting xxhash<0.5,>=0.4.3
  Using cached xxhash-0.4.3.zip (22 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Collecting requests>=2.4.0
  Using cached requests-2.27.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (63 kB)
Collecting certifi>=2017.4.17
  Using cached certifi-2021.10.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl (149 kB)
Collecting charset-normalizer~=2.0.0
  Using cached charset_normalizer-2.0.12-py3-none-any.whl (39 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.27,>=1.21.1 in c:\users\gulse\desktop\grafen\lib\site-packages (from requests>=2.4.0->PyVimeo<0.4,>=0.3.2->django-
vimeo) (1.26.9)
Collecting idna<4,>=2.5
  Using cached idna-3.3-py3-none-any.whl (61 kB)
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for django-vimeo, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for PyVimeo, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for xxhash, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Installing collected packages: xxhash, Django, certifi, idna, charset-normalizer, requests, PyVimeo, django-vimeo
  Running setup.py install for xxhash ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Running setup.py install for xxhash did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [17 lines of output]
      c:\users\gulse\desktop\grafen\lib\site-packages\setuptools\installer.py:30: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setuptools.installer is deprecated. Require
ments should be satisfied by a PEP 517 installer.
        SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning,
      WARNING: The wheel package is not available.
      running install
      c:\users\gulse\desktop\grafen\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py:37: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use b
uild and pip and other standards-based tools.
        setuptools.SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning,
      running build
      running build_ext
      building 'xxhash' extension
      creating build
      creating build\temp.win32-cpython-37
      creating build\temp.win32-cpython-37\Release
      creating build\temp.win32-cpython-37\Release\xxhash
      "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\HostX86\x86\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD
 -DVERSION=0.4.3 -DXXHASH_VERSION=r42 -Ic:\users\gulse\desktop\grafen\include -IC:\Users\gulse\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\include -IC:\Users
\gulse\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\includ
e" /Tcpython-xxhash.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-cpython-37\Release\python-xxhash.obj
      python-xxhash.c
      C:\Users\gulse\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\include\pyconfig.h(59): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'io.h': No such file or
 directory
      error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.29.30133\\bin\\HostX86\\x86\\cl.exe' failed w
ith exit code 2
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> xxhash

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.
```

При установке vimeo выходит эта ошибка, я устанавливала windows SDK 10 не помогло. Можете помочь